# plot histogram with feature on x-axis and each bar should reflect target class var with diff colors

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I don't even know how to correctly explain my problem in words so let me give an example instead.
Suppose I have a dataframe like this

```
d = {'feat':[1,1,1,2,3,4,5,1,4,5],'grade':['A','B','A','A','B','C','D','C','D','A']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1
    feat    grade
0   1   A
1   1   B
2   1   A
3   2   A
4   3   B
5   4   C
6   5   D
7   1   C
8   4   D
9   5   A
```

So I have a feature variable(`feat`) with a target class variable `grade` and my feature could fall only in one of A,B,C,D grade.
Now when I do this

```
df1.groupby('feat')['grade'].value_counts()
```

I get

```
feat  grade
1     A        2
      B        1
      C        1
2     A        1
3     B        1
4     C        1
      D        1
5     A        1
      D        1
Name: grade, dtype: int64
```

Now this is exact shape of my problem, I want to plot histogram of this dataframe such that x-axis would represent `feat` and each bar of this histogram would be made of different colors which would be proportional to occurrences of grades.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new dataframe with the result of groupby(), and use seaborn to plot the resulting histogram:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'feat':[1,1,1,2,3,4,5,1,4,5,1,2,2,4],'grade':['A','B','A','A','B','C','D','C','D','A','A','A','A','D']})
d = df.groupby('feat')['grade'].value_counts()
data = d.to_frame(name='number')
data = data.reset_index()
sns.barplot('feat','number',data=data,hue='grade')
```

Or if you don't want to use seaborn, you'll need to create a pivot table:

```
new_data = pd.pivot_table(data, values='number',index='feat',columns='grade')
new_data.plot.bar()
```